# my jwt token is sometimes recievable, or not recievable

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I'm practicing login using react and node.js. but have a problem. My jwt token is not receivable from backend.

I watched the video on YouTube and followed it. link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg2uPOKLC74&t=860s)  (sadly the youtuber doesnt have code in github:()

I think nodejs code doesn't have any problem. because I checked token by console.log no matter client receive token or not.

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
try {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password})


    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signin', body, config)
    

    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data
    })

    dispatch(loadUser());

} catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error })
}

}
```

I receive token using this code, it sometimes bring token or not. I also use async and await, but the problem always happen. When I use console.log to check response data it says undefined.
I checked code but think there is no mispelled.
I'm also using redux to login. weirdly, when I try to login, it appears new tab exatly same login page.  The problem also happening irregularly. And I use redux extensional devtools with chrome. When I try to login, redux states always initialized.
[image]

I have no idea why this happening. And when I failed to login, beginning append with '?' after url. like this.

[image]

I know it's hard to guess why this happening.
To see [my code](https://github.com/EminemBurger/Carona-front) detail
Thank you for read this.

Comment: Did you try your API with other app such as Postman?

Comment: no I haven't. I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: I've tried with Postman. And checked token come out normally.